# Dialogflow to Firestore using Inline Fulfillment - Get original user input from a certain parameter

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Is there a way to get the original input from a certain parameter?

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    function getData(agent) {
        let age = agent.parameters.age;
        let location = agent.parameters.location;
        let opinion = agent.parameters.opinion;
    
        db.collection("users").add({
            age: age, 
            location: location, 
            opinion: opinion
        });
    }

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('getData', getData);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

e.g. The user inputs "I love this thing!"

[This is the data that was stored in Firestore.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVxL3.png)

Notice that only the word "love" was stored in the opinion line since my [@opinion entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibD9i.png) has only the word love. This is the [getData intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vU75.png).

[This is what I'm trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7eIb.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you update your question to show the Intents where you have the `opinion` parameter?

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner! I've updated the question.  If it doesn't make any sense please let me know.